# How to parse XML's <media:text type="html"> with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I would be happy if there was someone who can tell me how to decode the following string from XML to PHP:

```
  <media:text type="html">
    <p> 
      <a href="foo.com">
        <img src="foo.com/foo.jpg" align="left" alt="Foo title" title="Foo title" border="0" />
      </a>
    </p>
  </media:text>
```

which is part of the following item:

```
<item>
  <title>Foo title</title>
  <description>Foo Description</description>
  <link>foo.com</link>
  <pubDate>Tue, 02 Feb 2021 18:23:51 EST</pubDate>
  <media:content url="foo.com/foo.jpg" />
  **<media:text type="html">
    <p> 
      <a href="foo.com">
        <img src="foo.com/foo.jpg" align="left" alt="Foo title" title="Foo title" border="0" />
      </a>
    </p>
  </media:text>**
</item>
```

With the code portion

```
$ content = $ xml-> channel-> item [$ i] -> children ('media', True) -> content-> attributes ();
```

I can only value content but I can't extract

```
<media: text type = "html">
```

Thanks to those who can help me!

Comment: When you say *I can only value content but I can't extract*, where is the issue?

Comment: I can't parse the portion of code:

<media:text type="html">
    <p> 
      <a href="foo.com">
        <img src="foo.com/foo.jpg" align="left" alt="Foo title" title="Foo title" border="0" />
      </a>
    </p>
  </media:text>

Comment: Can you check what `echo $xml->channel-> item [$i] -> children ('media', True)->text->children()->p->a['href'];` shows

Comment: `media:text` isn't nested inside `media:content`, it's next to it. So you'd access it the same way, but replacing "content" with "text".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SimpleXMLElement function to parse your XML, you will receive an array which will be easily parsed.

See https://www.php.net/manual/fr/simplexml.examples-basic.php.

Comment: From the code they have posted, it already looks as though they are using SimpleXML.